# URLをカーソルを移動させたとき表示するようにしたい

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

セルにURLを貼り付けた際、カーソルを移動させてもURL先が表示されなくなることがあるため、カーソルを移動させたときにURLが表示されるようにGASを組みました。

しかし、これではFor文内にgetValueメソッドを使用しているため、プロセスコストが高くなってしまいます。

かといって、TextFinderなどを使用して、V列を一括で処理するように組むことが自分にはできませんでした。
どなたかお知恵をお貸しください。

```
function Activation() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //スプレッドシートをGASで使う宣言
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ペースト&作業用シート'), true);
  for (i=12; i<=22; i++) {
    var  Cell = spreadsheet.getRange('V'+i).getValue();
    spreadsheet.getRange('V'+i).activate();
    if (Cell === ''){
    continue;
    }
  let  TextLong = spreadsheet.getRange('V'  +   i).getValue();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText(Cell)
  .setTextStyle(0, TextLong.length, SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
  .setForegroundColor('#1155cc')
  .setUnderline(true)
  .build())
  .build());
  debugger
  }
  }
```

[image: マクロ実行前のイメージ]
[image: マクロ実行後のイメージ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ハイパーリンクの挿入では駄目ですか？

```
function hyperlink() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ペースト&作業用シート'), true);
  var url = "https://www.kantei.go.jp/";
  var link = `=HYPERLINK("${url}", "${url}")`;
  speadsheet.getRange("V12").setFormula(link);
｝
```

Comment: URLは実際には10パターンあるのですが、for文を用いずにハイパーリンクの挿入ってできますか？

Comment: 技術的には別の質問になってしまいそうですね

回答ありがとうございます、別の質問を立てて相談してみますね